# how to fix Webexception unhandle

Tags: c#, exception

i want to make console c# program to download and execute a program.exe file from web.
so i get a "Webexception unhandle" error when i run this program.can any one help me. thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Downloader{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.1.exe");
        string filename = @"C:\bootable.exe";

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "anything");
            wc.DownloadFile(uri, filename);

        }
    }
}
```

}

can any one help me.

Comment: Show the error that you get. It likely contains quite a few hints as to why your download doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `WebException` occurs on the last line (please in future include that in your question - we can't *really* help you based on guesswork).

```
wc.DownloadFile(uri, filename);
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this method call, it will throw a `WebException` if one of the following is true:

1. The URI formed by combining BaseAddress and address is invalid.
2. filename is null or Empty.
3. The file does not exist.
4. An error occurred while downloading data.

We can rule out #2 immediately, as you've set that. To find out which of these situations you've got, try looking at the exception's message property (or the message property of the inner exception if there is one).